# Float return zero in golang

Tags: go

Why does this code always return zero:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var index_of_array int
    fmt.Scan(&index_of_array)
    var arr = make([]int, index_of_array)
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&arr[i])
    }

    positive := 0
    negative := 0
    zero_ := 0
    for _, arr_v := range arr {
        if arr_v > 0 {
            positive++
        } else if arr_v < 0 {
            negative++
        } else if arr_v == 0 {
            zero_++
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%f ", float32(positive/len(arr)))
    fmt.Printf("%f ", float32(negative/len(arr)))
    fmt.Printf("%f ", float32(zero_/len(arr)))

}
```

i mean to output

A decimal representing of the fraction of positive numbers in the array.
 A decimal representing of the fraction of negative numbers in the array.
 A decimal representing of the fraction of zeroes in the array.

Sample Input

6

-4 3 -9 0 4 1

Sample Output

0.500000

0.333333

0.166667

but in my code the output like this with the same input

0.000000

0.000000

0.000000

Comment: Hard to answer this if you don't supply the inputs you are typing and the output of the application

Comment: Because `float32(zero_/len(arr))` first divides an int by an int which gives you zero and then you convert that 0 to a float32 0. It should be `float32(zero_)/float32(len(arr))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some modifications to your code and it should run as you expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter the lenght of the array: ")
    scanner.Scan()
    index_of_array, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    if err != nil {
        panic("Errroor!")
    }

    arr := make([]int, index_of_array)

    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Enter value number %d: ", i+1)
        scanner.Scan()
        arr[i], err = strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            panic("Error 2!")
        }
    }

    positive := 0
    negative := 0
    zero_ := 0
    for _, arr_v := range arr {
        if arr_v > 0 {
            positive++
        } else if arr_v < 0 {
            negative++
        } else if arr_v == 0 {
            zero_++
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Array entered: ", arr)
    fmt.Printf("There are %d positive number(s) of %d in the array. Fraction: %.6f\n", positive, len(arr), float64(positive)/float64(len(arr)))
    fmt.Printf("There are %d negative number(s) of %d in the array. Fraction: %.6f\n", negative, len(arr), float64(negative)/float64(len(arr)))
    fmt.Printf("There are %d zero(s) of %d in the array. Fraction: %.6f\n", zero_, len(arr), float64(zero_)/ float64(len(arr)))

}
```

you can run it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/FgfQ/2)

And you can use it like this example:

```
Enter the lenght of the array: 6
Enter value number 1: -4
Enter value number 2: 3
Enter value number 3: -9
Enter value number 4: 0
Enter value number 5: 4
Enter value number 6: 1
Array entered:  [-4 3 -9 0 4 1]
There are 3 positive number(s) of 6 in the array. Fraction: 0.500000
There are 2 negative number(s) of 6 in the array. Fraction: 0.333333
There are 1 zero(s) of 6 in the array. Fraction: 0.166667
```

Comment: Welcome. Glade that my answer is helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the first variable you get from the user is the length of the array not the index... Secondly you should prompt the user when asking for user input like so:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  var length int
  fmt.Print("Please enter the length of the array: ")
  fmt.Scan(&length)

  var arr = make([]int, length)
  for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("Please enter the value at index %d of the array: ", i)
    fmt.Scan(&arr[i])
  }

  fmt.Println("You entered the array: ", arr)

  positive := 0
  negative := 0
  zero := 0
  for _, arr_v := range arr {
    if arr_v > 0 {
      positive++
    } else if arr_v < 0 {
      negative++
    } else if arr_v == 0 {
      zero++
    }
  }

  fmt.Printf("There are %d postive numbers in the array\n", int32(positive))
  fmt.Printf("There are %d negative numbers in the array\n", int32(negative))
  fmt.Printf("There are %d zeroes in the array", int32(zero))
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter the length of the array:  4
Please enter the value at index 0 of the array:  7
Please enter the value at index 1 of the array:  0
Please enter the value at index 2 of the array:  -9
Please enter the value at index 3 of the array:  8
You entered the array:  [7 0 -9 8]
There are 2 postive numbers in the array
There are 1 negative numbers in the array
There are 1 zeroes in the array
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FgfQ/0)

Comment: i mean to output

A decimal representing of the fraction of positive numbers in the array. A decimal representing of the fraction of negative numbers in the array. A decimal representing of the fraction of zeroes in the array.

Sample Input

6

-4 3 -9 0 4 1

Sample Output

0.500000

0.333333

0.166667

but in my code the output like this with the same input

1.000000

0.000000

0.000000